# Using Vue components with props

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm doing a Vue school course and I'm trying to do a little exercise with components and props. I'm trying to buid a simple button and paragraph component that takes the content of a paragraph as the prop's value:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Click-Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Vue.js Components Fundamentals</h1>
        <click-counter click-title="The first counter is:"></click-counter>
        <click-counter click-title="The second counter is:"></click-counter>
        <click-counter click-title="The Third counter is:"></click-counter>
    </div>

    <script type="text/x-template" id="click-counter-template">
        <div>
            <p>{{ click-title }}</p>
            <button v-on:click="count++"> {{ count }} </button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
Vue.component('click-counter', {
    props: {
        'click-title': {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        count: 0
      }
    },
    template: '#click-counter-template',
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

The thing is that the content of the *click-title* prop is being evaluated but not rendered.

**Screenshot of the Vue extension**

[image: Vue extension]

**Screenshot of the page's content**

[image: content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that, for Vue to understand that the prop in the app.js file and the index.html file are the same thing, you have to use camelCase in *app.js* (and when you define the component) and kebab-case in index.html (in the instances of the component).

In short, I changed this:

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Some Head Info -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Vue.js Components Fundamentals</h1>
        <!-- USE kebab-case HERE (click-title) -->
        <click-counter click-title="The first counter is:"></click-counter>
        <click-counter click-title="The second counter is:"></click-counter>
        <click-counter click-title="The Third counter is:"></click-counter>
    </div>

    <script type="text/x-template" id="click-counter-template">
        <div>
            <!-- USE camelCase HERE (clickTitle) -->
            <p>{{ clickTitle }}</p>
            <button v-on:click="count++"> {{ count }} </button>
        </div>
    </script>
    
    <!-- More stuff -->
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```js
Vue.component('click-counter', {
    props: {
        // USE camelCase HERE (clickTitle)
        'clickTitle': {
            // Atributes
        }
    },
    data () {
      // Variables
    },
    // Template
})

// New Vue
```